# Criar uma string de comparação no Java

Tags: java, string

Quando coloco para executar o código pelo Eclipse e chego na parte de digitar o login dá um erro o qual eu não e não vai para a próxima fase que é a de digitar a senha. Queria uma ajuda de como resolver esse problema, obrigado. Obs. Sou estudante de Sistema de Informação e estou no primeiro ano ainda, por isso sou leigo no assunto ainda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declaração das variáveis
        String nome, cidade, estado, senha, login, senha1, login1;
        int codigo, idade;
        double valor, valorFinal, desconto, valordescontado, ddesconto, vdescont;

        // leitura dos dados
        System.out.println("Bem vindo! by. EduardoMarecki");
        System.out.println("\nFaça seu cadastro abaixo - ");
        nome = Console.readString("\nDigite seu nome: ");
        idade = Console.readInt("Digite sua idade: ");
        cidade = Console.readString("Digite sua cidade: ");
        estado = Console.readString("Digite seu estado: ");
        login = Console.readString("Digite um login: ");
        login1 = Console.readString("Digite seu login novamente: ");
        senha = Console.readString("Digite uma senha: ");
        senha1 = Console.readString("Digite sua senha novamente: ");
        System.out.println("Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!");
        System.out.println("Faça o login para continuar: ");


        ***while (login != login1){
            login1 = Console.readString ("Digite seu login: ");
        }


        while (senha != senha1){
            senha1 = Console.readString("Digite sua senha: ");

        }***



        System.out.println("Login efetuado com sucesso! ");

        codigo = Console.readInt("\nInforme o código do produto: ");
        valor = Console.readDouble("Informe o valor do produto: R$ ");
        ddesconto = Console.readInt("Informe o valor do desconto: ");

        // processamento:

        vdescont = ddesconto / 100;

        // calculando o desconto:

        desconto = valor * vdescont;

        valorFinal = valor - desconto;
        valordescontado = valor - valorFinal;

        // saída de dados:
        System.out.println("\n\nParabéns! Compra finalizada com sucesso!");
        System.out.println("Dados cadastrados: ");
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
        System.out.println("Idade: " + idade);
        System.out.println("Cidade: " + cidade);
        System.out.println("Estado: " + estado);
        System.out.println("\nInformações sobre a compra: ");
        System.out.println("Produto: " + codigo);
        System.out.println("Valor: R$ " + valor);
        System.out.println("Desconto de: %" + ddesconto);
        System.out.println("Valor final com desconto: R$ " + valorFinal);
        System.out.println("Valor descontado: " + valordescontado);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Em java, os operadores `==` e `!=` comparam a referência da instância e não o valor delas.
Ao usar `==` para comparar instâncias em java você vai estar perguntando se as variáveis tem a mesma referência.

Se você quer saber se duas strings, ou qualquer outro objeto em java, tem o mesmo valor, você deve usar a função `equals()`.

Ao fazer `login != login1`, você está perguntando: *A variável* `login` *não tem a mesma referencia que a variável* `login1`*?*
E nesse caso vai SEMPRE retornar falso, e vai ficar iterando sempre nesse while.

Ao invés de:

```
while (login != login1){
    login1 = Console.readString ("Digite seu login: ");
}
```

Faça:

```
while (login != null && !login.equals(login1)){
    login1 = Console.readString ("Digite seu login: ");
}
```

Faça a mesma coisa com a senha.

Com strings, particularmente, os operadores `==` e `!=` podem funcionar.
Se você declarar:

```
String s1 = "teste";
String s2 = "teste";
```

`s1 == s1` vai retornar `true`. Mas isso acontece por causa do [string pool](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/).

Comment: Só lembrando que o equals é usado apenas para objetos, ou seja, tipos primitivos serão comparados com os operadores == e != sem maiores problemas. Como o tipo String no Java é um Object, então deve-se usar o equals.